# Request JSON (http post) com Angular 2+

Tags: angular

estou tentando consumir uma api na sandbox da braspag e estou recebendo uma mensagem de erro: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://apisandbox.braspag.com.br/v2/sales/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
Desativando o CORS eu obtenho a seguinte mensagem de erro: XMLHttpRequest cannot load (apibraspag). Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404. Contudo, através de Html/jQuery, a requisição é efetuada com sucesso. 
Meu código:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
@Component({
selector: 'app-app-pagamento',
templateUrl: './app-pagamento.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app-pagamento.component.css']
})
export class AppPagamentoComponent implements OnInit {

http: Http;
constructor(http: Http) {
 this.http = http;
}

efetuarCompra() {
  let req = {
    "MerchantOrderId": "2014111703",
    "Customer": {
      "Name": "Comprador Teste"
    },
    "Payment": {
      "Type": "CreditCard",
      "Amount": 15700,
      "Provider": "Simulado",
      "Installments": 1,
      "CreditCard": {
      "CardNumber": "1234123412341231",
      "Holder": "Teste Holder",
      "ExpirationDate": "12/2021",
      "SecurityCode": "123",
      "Brand": "Visa"
      }
    }
  }

let hd = new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'MerchantId': '6d086058-35e5-4530-92b0-b2c8cd9c77ec',
  'MerchantKey': 'ILIPGAYWVALZWEKNNTHMDJZWRPISPIDYLGSWSXIH',
  'RequestId': 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
});



this.http.post('https://apisandbox.braspag.com.br/v2/sales/', 
JSON.stringify(req), {headers: hd} )
   .subscribe(() => {
    console.log('Payment Sucess')
   }, erro => console.log(erro));

}

ngOnInit() {
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

É necessário garantir que o servidor na qual está integrando tenha suporte a CORS.

Outro ponto importante é verificar aspectos de segurança para garantir que não tenham acesso a sua MerchantId e sua MerchantKey e analisar se não é melhor manter no lado do servidor essa informação.

Answer (score 0):

Digite esses seguintes códigos no arquivo do servidor que precisa ser acessado, caso tenha acesso, caso não tenha, mande ele junto com a requisição http no angular.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
```

Answer (score 0):

A API de pagamentos não suporta CORS, logo isso não funcionará e não é aconselhável que você deixe seu Secret no lado cliente pois será fácil rouba-lo e utiliza-lo para cancelar transações ou testar cartões roubados.

Answer (score 0):

Tentei simular seu problema mas não consegui, o código abaixo funcionou perfeitamente (testado no Stackblitz):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const url = 'https://apisandbox.braspag.com.br/v2/sales/';
    const data = {
      "MerchantOrderId": "2014111703",
      "Customer": {
        "Name": "Comprador Teste"
      },
      "Payment": {
        "Type": "CreditCard",
        "Amount": 15700,
        "Provider": "Simulado",
        "Installments": 1,
        "CreditCard": {
        "CardNumber": "1234123412341231",
        "Holder": "Teste Holder",
        "ExpirationDate": "12/2021",
        "SecurityCode": "123",
        "Brand": "Visa"
        }
      }
    };

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'MerchantId': '6d086058-35e5-4530-92b0-b2c8cd9c77ec',
      'MerchantKey': 'ILIPGAYWVALZWEKNNTHMDJZWRPISPIDYLGSWSXIH',
      'RequestId': 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    });

    this.http.post(url, data, { headers })
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log('Finalizado', response);
      });
  }
}
```